# Google Big Query runs slower on smaller sized table than bigger table of same schema

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am running a query on a table which has data similar to following format:

```
store_name,region,state,town, product_name,product_category,product_sub, volume, month
```

The table size is 12GB. If I run a query similar to this

```
select sum(volume), store_name,region,product_name,product_category from mybigquery where region in ("Region A","Region B", "Region C") and product_category in ("Product Category 1","Product Category B") group by region,product_category
```

The query scans around 70% of the whole table and as I add columns to the where clause the total scan data increases and thereby increasing costs. The time taken to get a result is around 30 seconds

To save me the costs I divided my data and created month-wise tables (size around 1 GB each). Now the amount of data scanned per query on the month-wise tables is 1/10 the data scan on the full year table. But surprisingly the time taken has quadrupled to 2 minutes.

What is the reason for such strange behaviour?
Is this something Google Big Query does to have big data scans by users and thereby getting better revenue?

Comment: Have you read about [partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables)? It's generally fastest to query a date partitioned table rather than creating a "regular" table for each day and querying multiple at once, if I understand what you're describing.

Comment: Partitioning is by day not by month and year. I may have different such units of time in future. Also my solution needing to be transformed as per the DB is not ideal for me. What if tomorrow I move to some other platform. I will need to change a lot of code.

Comment: Why is it that smaller dataset query result times are slower than bigger dataset? That is my basic question. Lets say if i had divided the tables on the basis of regions. In that case also the query comes to be slower. It seems google assigns hardware on the basis of table size and the assignment is not linear.